# Building Freemarker from source

Tags: java, security, ant, build-process, freemarker

I am working on a security project at my university for open source software. I am trying to build freemarker from source, but I am running into some problems. Everything that I can find online says that simple running 'ant' in the root directory should build the project. The only requirement is that you have ant v1.7.0 installed, which I do.

When I go into the root directory and type 'ant' I get the following output:

```
Buildfile: build.xml

init:

_autoget-deps:

update-deps:
     [echo] Getting dependencies...
     [echo] -------------------------------------------------------

BUILD FAILED
/media/osr/runs/java/freemarker/freemarker/trunk/freemarker/build.xml:64: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/osr/runs/java/freemarker/freemarker/trunk/freemarker/build.xml:567: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/osr/runs/java/freemarker/freemarker/trunk/freemarker/build.xml:575: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:settings
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/home/murrayj/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument


Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the build.xml does not have a default target.  try this instead

```
ant compile
```

**edit:** changed target

Comment: I tried running 'ant all' but got a BUILD FAILED error stating that Target "all" does not exist in the project.

Comment: @johnmurray, i have changed the target, please give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need Apache Ivy. We've changed the build process for some time now; it now uses Ivy instead of manual dependency management.

Comment: Can I add ivy simply by downloading the ivy JAR file and adding it to the ant/lib directory?

Comment: I did that and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu/Debian installing Ivy also involves manually adding it to 
the ant classpath.

Whilst this may not be the cleanest way to do it [1]

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/java/ivy.jar /usr/share/ant/lib/ivy.jar
```

[1] http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=547969

Answer (score 0):

After installing ivy, running

`ant compile`

worked just fine.

Thank you!